# Place a element at bottom of the print page without fixed position?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div in a page that contains a copyright notice. This div is the last element in the page, so it renders fine on the browser. It also renders the same way on a print page. But when I print this id like this div item to 'float' to the bottom on the whatever page it is on (so if the page is only half full, the div item would still be at the bottom of the page).

Lots of Google'ing Ive read recommends using the "position: fixed; bottom:0;"... The problem with this method is that it will sometimes go over important text on the print page.

In the perfect word id love to get this div on every print page, without it EVER going over any text. But assuming that cannot be done, can I at least get it to the bottom of the page it is on without it going over any text?

note: I tried using a negative 'bottom' value, but some of the text of the div itself was cutoff, and not sure how well supported that method would be.

Comment: Add a `padding-bottom` to the `body` element, that would equals the height of the element you want in page bottom.

Comment: if you tried putting it on the bottom of the page, and it covered up text, then where should it have gone otherwise? If there is text on the very bottom, then wouldn't it always cover up text unless it went to the next page?

Comment: not to mention it just causes a scroll bar to appear if there's sufficient content on the page

Answer (score 0):

With help of `media print` you can call whatever `css` you want to appear only while `printing`.

like this:

```
@media print {
    p {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Apply `position:absolute;` for the copyright div and see the `height of copyright div` and provide that much `padding bottom` for `above div` so your text won't overlap on copyright div.

Or

And to make your `copyright div` float always at the bottom without overlapping above text then you have to give fix height for the above div so copyright div appears at bottom.